# "ubiquity crashed with indexError in free_space(); list out of range" when installing ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubiquity

During ubuntu 16.04 installation, after selecting language and continue, it stop and give me some problem. and this is the screenshot

[image]

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the issue. I found it was because of partition table error. Eventually I used testdisk to fix it.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

You can run Gparted to check if disk partition table messed.

Comment: thanks alot Henry. your answer has solved my problem. may Allah reward you. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

What is your HDD space? How much RAM do you have? It seems like Ubuntu is filling up the RAM and then the installation crashes, giving you that error because the RAM is full.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. HDD size is 40GB and ram is 6GB